# Center horizontally div elements inside bootstrap? (text-center not working)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with the text-center class of bootstrap not working, here is it.

I have a div that contains several list and other tags, but when I apply the text-center class to make this center on the screen it does nothing, this applies also in a div that contains divs in shapes, here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 options-bar text-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="normal-li">Ordenar por: </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
            Status <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
            Clientes <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
            Fecha <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
            Productos <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
            Asignación <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="normal-li">Ver por: </li>
        <li><input type="radio"><label style="color: rgb(46, 116, 241 );">Solicitud</label></li>
        <li><input type="radio"><label style="color: rgb(46, 116, 241 );">Producto</label></li>
        <li id="clock"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar solicitudes">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see my div with class `options-bar` is the one that contains the rest, but the class text-center does nothing.

Here is my css stylesheet for `options-bar`:

```
.options-bar  {
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question? Are you talking about aligning vertically?

Comment: Sorry, it was to center horizontally

Comment: Can you please explain in detail because the question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `.nav.nav-pills li` items to `flex-grow: 1;` which will cause all the list items to expand equally to fill the space. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9ehzkgj/) for an example. I also added a snippet below, but it only looks right in full-screen.

```css
.options-bar  {
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav.nav-pills li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 options-bar text-center">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="normal-li">Ordenar por: </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                        Status <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                        Clientes <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                        Fecha <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                        Productos <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                        Asignación <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="normal-li">Ver por: </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio">
      <label style="color: rgb(46, 116, 241 );">Solicitud</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio">
      <label style="color: rgb(46, 116, 241 );">Producto</label>
    </li>
    <li id="clock"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar solicitudes">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Is it producing different behavior? etc, etc.

Comment: It does nothing, I also removed styles that I didn't use anymore to see if that helped, but no, the view is not affected. Also the inspector do not show the `flex-grow: 1;`

Comment: Hm. Sounds like maybe it's being overridden by another style? Try playing around with the specificity of the CSS block (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). For example, try `ul.nav.nav-pills li` instead. Or try adding `!important`. I don't really like `!important` but it can be helpful when trying to override bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this for centering div's. Add the below code to the div that you want to center.

```
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note: Usually div's occupy entire width(since its a block element). Make sure that the div which you want to center has width lesser than the screen width. Otherwise you may not see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css class in your divs:

```
.vertCenter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
```